# Android's XML Parsing technique

Tags: android, parsing, manifest

Which Parser is used by Android Framework to parse Manifest, layout files? Can we also use the same within our application. I am trying to get at best xml parser keeping performance, memory and reliability in mind. Ofcourse depends on size of xml.

Answer (score 1):

Without really going through all of the AOSP code, it's difficult to say.  unfortunately I wouldn't even know where to beging going through all of that code.

However, the javax.xml.* libraries are included in the Dalvik VM. The Dalvik VM was the defacto VM since the beginning of Android (I saw was, because now in Lollipop, ART is the standard).  So it is probably a pretty safe bet to assume that the Android Framework uses javax.xml.parsers to parse the xml files from apk files.